# Anonymous script firing with each pageload gtm.js and seems like a hack

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I seem to be experiencing an issue where a random third party script keeps executing with each pageload on my site. I have a lot of pageview and event tracking in place and all of that is managed via GTM.

Script --

```
setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.src=document.location.protocol+"//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0017/9988.js?"+Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/36E5);a.async=!0;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)},1);
```

The above third party script is injecting an empty document inside the header tag. The body and the header of the doc is completely empty.The query parameter in the injected doc keeps changing.

Has anyone else has experienced this issue in the past? Any ideas what this could be?

I also have a lot of customjs variables in GTM - I wanted to see if I could search for this piece of code in one of the custom js variables - anyone knows if there is an easy way to search through all variables without going into each one at a time?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Export your container as JSON file:

1. In Google Tag Manager, navigate to the desired container.
2. In the top navigation, go to Admin and then Export Container.
3. Select the desired container version from the selector.
4. Preview and confirm your export file and click Download.

(link to source: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997?hl=en)

Once you donwlaod the JSON file open it in any text editor and search for the code, or simply search just for the specific domain in the tag e.g. "dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net". The name name of the Tag or Variable will appear in the corresponding object.

For example you should see something like this (if the code is in html tag):

```
    ...
    "tag": [
                    {
                        "accountId": "001",
                        "containerId": "123",
                        "tagId": "3",
                        "name": "THIS IS THE NAME OF YOUR TAG",
                        "type": "html",
                        "parameter": [
                            {
                                "type": "TEMPLATE",
                                "key": "html",
                                "value": "setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.src=document.location.protocol+"//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0017/9988.js?"+Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/36E5);a.async=!0;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)},1);"
                            },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation this seems to be the tracking code for Crazy Egg](https://guides.co/g/a-beginners-guide-to-crazyegg/13092) (heat maps and scroll maps) - the cloudfront URL matches. The parameter keeps changing because it's a random number generated by javascript to prevent caching.

This is obviously not part of GTM. Either you have configured this yourself in GTM or somewhere in your website, or you include a marketing tag (via custom HTML) that load Crazy Egg (which without a contract and a data processing agreement would be unethical and in many jurisdictions illegal).